# PyQt5 Right Click treeWidget Item

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-3.5

Hi I'm working on a project in Python 3.5 and Pyqt5, I want to add a right click on a treeWidget Item so I can create a contextual menu with actions, but I didn't find that in PyQt5.

Answer (score 3):

Problem Solved actually, so this is how you add a right click contextual menu in a QtreeWidget Area

```
 def menuContextuelAlbum(self, event):
    self.menu_contextuelAlb = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.treeWidget)
    ajoutFileAtt = self.menu_contextuelAlb.addAction("Ajouter l'album à la file d'attente")
    action2 = self.menu_contextuelAlb.exec_(self.treeWidget.mapToGlobal(event))
    if action2 is not None:
        if action2 == ajoutFileAtt:
            self.addAlbumlistAtt()
```

and launch it with:

```
    self.treeWidget.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)  
    self.treeWidget.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.menuContextuelAlbum)  
    self.actionOuvrir.triggered.connect(self.menu)
```

Answer (score 3):

To post an updated answer. This is what worked for me:

```
class MainWindow_W():
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.MainWindow)



        # Connect the contextmenu
        self.ui.treeWidget.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.ui.treeWidget.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.menuContextTree)


    def menuContextTree(self, point):
        # Infos about the node selected.
        index = self.ui.treeWidget.indexAt(point)

        if not index.isValid():
            return

        item = self.ui.treeWidget.itemAt(point)
        name = item.text(0)  # The text of the node.

        # We build the menu.
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
        action = menu.addAction("Souris au-dessus de")
        action = menu.addAction(name)
        menu.addSeparator()
        action_1 = menu.addAction("Choix 1")
        action_2 = menu.addAction("Choix 2")
        action_3 = menu.addAction("Choix 3")


        menu.exec_(self.ui.treeWidget.mapToGlobal(point))
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create your own `QTreeWidget` with your own `mousePressEvent`.
in your `mousePressEvent` check if the event type is a right click and if it is, do whatever you want. Then, when you add widgets in your tree, **make sure it will be your class which is added and not a `QTreeWidget`**.

So something like that:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import QTreeWidgetItem
import sys

class MyTreeWidget(QtGui.QTreeWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QTreeWidget.__init__(self, parent)
    def mousePressEvent (self, event):
        print("child clicked ! ")
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.RightButton:
            print("right click !")
        QtGui.QTreeWidget.mousePressEvent(self, event)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    QtGui.qApp = app
    pointListBox = MyTreeWidget()
    root = QTreeWidgetItem(pointListBox, ["root"])
    A = QTreeWidgetItem(root, ["A"])
    barA = QTreeWidgetItem(A, ["bar", "i", "ii"])
    bazA = QTreeWidgetItem(A, ["baz", "a", "b"])

    pointListBox.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, how can I Try it in a file apart ?
`if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MytreeWidgetItem()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())`

Comment: You were right to ask there was many errors in my code. I will fix that with a working example.

Comment: Thanks, but the topic was about PyQt5 as there is not too much documentation about it, it's a little bit annoying, and PyQt5 doesn't use really same objects as PyQt4. But thanks for your answer

Comment: Actually I found translating PyQt4 to pyqt5 to be fairly straight forward without to many issues.  Sometimes all I have to do is swap the PyQt4 references for PyQt5 references so the above answer just might be viable with a bit of tweaking